# Inconsistency with date fields in the API

Tags: api, extension, gsoc

I've been working on an extension for civicrm and am using the API to retrieve fields to be used in forms presented to the end user.

I am using the 'html.type' returned to determine which type of html form input to display (text, textarea, select, etc.).

The first issue is that the returned values don't match up with html input types, for example:

```
CRM.api3('Contact', 'getfield', {
  "sequential": 1,
  "name": "birth_date",
  "action": "get"
})
```

returns

```
"values": {
    "name": "birth_date",
    ...
    "html": {
        "type": "Select Date"
    }
}
```

but `Select Date` is not an html input type. This isn't too much of a problem as long as Civi is consistent with what it calls a date field. But in the above example, the field `birth_date` expects a date without a time.

But calling

```
CRM.api3('Event', 'getfield', {
  "sequential": 1,
  "name": "event_start_date",
  "action": "get"
}
```

returns the same 'html.type' value:

```
"values": {
    "name": "start_date",
    ...
    "html": {
        "type": "Select Date"
    },
    ...
}
```

and yet this field expects a datetime, not just a date.

So if you're trying (as I am) to have an extension operate on a list of fields which can be selected by the user and so aren't known in advance, I can't see any way to differentiate between the two cases.

I may be missing something obvious, but I can't work out what.

Answer (score 1):

We've worked this out to handle form creation for civicrm fields in the CiviCRM entity project. https://drupal.org/project/civicrm_entity

We use the 'type' property returned from a getfields api call like so:
This code here we determine what widget to use:
checkout civicrm_entity.module 
civicrm_entity_get_field_widget()
the section pertaining to dates:

```
 if (isset($field_spec['type'])) {

        switch($field_spec['type']) {
          case 4:
            $widget = array('widget' => 'date_select','format' => 'Y:m:d');
            break;
          case 8:
            $widget = array('widget' => 'date_select','format' => 'H:i:s');
            break;
          case 12:
            $widget = array('widget' => 'date_select','format' => 'Y:m:d H:i:s');
            break;
        }
      }
```

so the '#type' of the form element is set to 'date_select' and the format is used to set the '#format' property
this does require the date_api module from the Date project

Comment: Thank you, this looks like a good workaround, but I still think this shouldn't be necessary.